# microsoft sql server - calculate return between every row and the last row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like the following:

```
+-------+--------------+
| Value |       Date   |
+-------+--------------+
|    14 | 10/11/2010   |
|    12 | 10/12/2010   |
|    12 | 10/13/2010   |
|    10 | 10/14/2010   |
|    8  | 10/15/2010   |
|    6  | 10/16/2010   |
|    4  | 10/17/2010   |
|    2  | 10/18/2010   |
+-------+--------------+
```

I would like to calculate the return (the quotient) between every row and the last row (which is with the latest date). e.g for the row with date "10/16/2010", the result should be 6/2=3

Hence, the resulting table should be

```
+-------+--------------+
| result|       Date   |
+-------+--------------+
|    7  | 10/11/2010   |
|    6  | 10/12/2010   |
|    6  | 10/13/2010   |
|    5  | 10/14/2010   |
|    4  | 10/15/2010   |
|    3  | 10/16/2010   |
|    2  | 10/17/2010   |
|    1  | 10/18/2010   |
+-------+--------------+
```

Is it possible to complete this? thanks you!

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: well. i only know it is microsoft sql server, actually, i am using another software (third party) which requires me to wrote some custom SQL query to extract date from  the server.

Comment: What does `SELECT @@VERSION` return?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value you want to divide by.  Since that's always going to be a single row, you can just use a cross  join to join to that and perform your division.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ecda1/9)

```
with maxdate as
(select max([Date]) as maxdate from table1),
divby as
(select
   value as divby
 from
   table1
 inner join maxdate md
   on md.maxdate = table1.[date])


 select
 value / divby
,[date]
 from
 table1
 cross join divby
```

To break it down a bit, the first CTE (cleverly named maxdate) gets the maximum date for the whole thing.  The second CTE (divby) get the value (that you will be dividing by) for that max date.  As long as you only get one row back from that, you can safely use a cross join, resulting in each row in your table being divided by that one value.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution `JOIN` the the table to itself.

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7f9fa/1)

```
select (t1b.value / t1a.value) as result, 
  t1b.date from table1 t1a
join table1 t1b on t1a.date = (select max(date) from table1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the fiddle, Andrew!  Can be accomplished like this as well if 2008 and above (fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ecda1/11):

```
SELECT   [Value] / MIN([Value]) OVER () AS result,
         [Date]
FROM     Table1
```